# tcp socket how to wait message sent and acked

Tags: linux, sockets

As we know the messages in buffer shall be still sent out even after socket closed. this is usefull, but there's a use case that we want to wait the messages is sent and acked by peer,

e.g. in embeded device, a firmware upgrade function in web ui. after upgrade done a message is sent to web ui then reboot the device. we want the message is sent and acked, or reboot may drop messages. then web ui lost reply.

so, is there a way in linux wait a socket (closed or not closed) sent out and acked all messages ?

Comment: send a message back. Most OSes don't tell you about ACK packets.

Comment: @user253751 can't this be only done by applicantion layer ? bad design ~

Comment: If you are using the normal sockets libraries in c, you can use raw sockets and packet sniffing. There is a setting to view headers as well.

Comment: @yuanjianpeng actually it is bad design to rely on the ACK in transport layer. The receiving OS will send an ACK as soon as it receives the packet - before the application layer receives it. If you want to know the application layer has received it, then you need to use an application layer ACK.

Comment: @user253751 OS acked is enough for the above use case. once we receive the peer's ack, our work is done, and can reboot safely without message loss.